# How could I make text input screen after changing the text is automatically deleted, when I go back to login screen

Tags: python, kivy

imports:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
```

```
kv = '''
<Login>
    name:'Login'
    ben: benName.text
    pw: passwort.text
    knopf: btn
    knopff: btnn
 
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size: root.width,root.height
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text: "Username"
                font_size: 25
            TextInput:
                id: benName
                multiline: False
                font_size: 30
            Label:
                text: "Password"
                font_size: 25
                bold: True
            TextInput:
                password: True
                id: passwort
                multiline: False
                font_size: 40
        Button:
            size_hint: (1.,1.10)
            text:" Start "
            id: btn
            font_size: 40
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = "data" if passwort.text == "1" and benName.text == "1" else "Login"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "down"
        Button:
            size_hint: (1.,1.10)
            text: " Exit "
            id: btnn
            font_size: 40
            on_release: app.stop()


<data>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text:
                "hallo"
        Button:
            text: " back "
            on_press:
                root.clear_inputs()
                root.manager.current = "Login"

'''
```

`MyApp` class:

```
class Login(Screen):
    ben = StringProperty()
    pw = StringProperty()
    knopf = ObjectProperty()


class MyApp(App):
    Builder.load_string(kv)
 
    def build(self):
        ms = ScreenManager()
        ms.add_widget(Login(name='Login'))
        ms.add_widget(data(name='data'))
        self.title = "MyApp"
        return ms




class data(Screen):

    def clear_inputs(self):
        login = self.manager.get_screen('Login')
        for child in reversed(login.ids.container.children):
            if isinstance(child, TextInput):
                child.text = ''




if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, but I notice that the `container` id is used in `clear_inputs()`,  but is never defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just access their IDs in a method and then set their text to "" when entering screen, by using on_pre_enter, this method is fired whenever u enter the screen, even if you leave and enter again, it will run

```
class Login (Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self):
        self.ids['benName'].text = ""
        self.ids['passwort'].text = ""
```